# How to set up a Chef Node on an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to use knife bootstrap command from mac terminal
"knife bootstrap node_domain_or_IP -x username -P password -N name_for_node --sudo"

But the problem is, I don't have user name and password, instead the ec2-user has this private key  stored in my local work station which helps me to connect to the server.
I find lot of examples for debian os, but hard to find for RHEL on ec2.

OS: RHEL 6
Chef: 11.1.6

Kindly let me know if any details you need to help me better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with host keys you will have a username.  Typically, if you are using

`ssh -i somekey user@host_or_ip`

to ssh to your node, then you would use

`knife bootstrap node_domain_or_IP -x username -i sameKey -N chef_name_you_want --sudo`

Notice, I use `-i` rather than `-P`.  That's all there is to it.

An even better option for most people is to use `knife ec2 server create` to create your node in the first place.  This will create the node in AWS and bootstrap it, all in one command.